# How to get Element using useRef in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to add some event on a schedule card of [tui.calendar](https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.react-calendar). I tried to get the root element then querySelectorAll the schedule card's attribute.

The schedule card, calendarRef exists. the root element from `getRootElement` exists the div tag of the schedules card, but my `element` still empty.

What is wrong? My purpose is to get the schedule card element then add contextmenu for each. Thanks!

Update: I changed useLayoutEffect to useEffect then it's work. But only on Codesanbox not my project :D I don't know why?

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-goldstine-ohc9e?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. It looks like it works. I've just got an instance of a calendar with `getInstance()` and then got a reference to the DOM element via `instance.getElement(sc.id,sc.calendarId)`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (calendarRef && calendarRef.current) {
      const instance = calendarRef.current.getInstance();
      schedules.forEach((sc) => {
        /*
        const instance = calendarRef.current?.getRootElement();
        const element = instance.getElementsByClassName(
          "tui-full-calendar-time-schedule "
        );
        const elementArr = Array.from(element!);
        console.log(elementArr);
        */
        console.log(instance.getElement(sc.id,sc.calendarId));
      });
    }
  });
```